# How to configure subnet with azure privateendpoints to permit microsoft hosted agents access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps

I have a pipeline deploying in a WebApp without problem, but I need activate a PrivateEnpoint to restrict access to this WebApp.

I did it, but with the PrivateEndpoint enabled the Microsoft Hosted Agents do not connect with the WebApp, then my pipeline fail.

Then:

- I created a NSG with allow rule to permit traffic to my subnet (Same subnet with the PrivateEndpoint)
- I associated the NSG with my subnet.
- I disabled networking rules of privateendpoint in my subnet with az cli:

`az network vnet subnet update --name <subnet-name> --resource-group <rg-name> --vnet-name <vnet-name>--disable-private-**link**-service-network-policies true`

And,

`az network vnet subnet update --name <subnet-name> --resource-group <rg-name> --vnet-name <vnet-name> --disable-private-**endpoint**-service-network-policies true`

In my powershell script, I catch the agent IP and make an upgrade of NSG to permit this source to my subnet.

But, nothing!

The Microsoft Hosted Agents do not connect with the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

For Kudu REST API (deployment with Azure DevOps self-hosted agent), you must create two records pointing to the Private Endpoint IP in your Azure DNS private zone or your custom DNS server. The first is for your Web App, the second is for the SCM of your Web App.

**Name  | Type | Value |** Checkout this doc: [private-endpoint#dns](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#dns)

mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net  | A |   PrivateEndpointIP |

mywebapp.scm.privatelink.azurewebsites.net |    A |     PrivateEndpointIP |

Additionally, just to highlight-  Private Endpoint is only used for incoming flows to your Web App. Outgoing flows won't use this Private Endpoint. You can inject outgoing flows to your network in a different subnet through the VNet integration feature.

Note that the VNet integration feature cannot use the same subnet as Private Endpoint, this is a limitation of the VNet integration feature.Kindly check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#conceptual-overview) for additional info.

Comment: This was the magic I was missing, thanks. In my case, I was deploying from a vnet-based self-hosted agent (vmss) to a function within a vnet and was missing the binding between the private endpoint for the function and the dns records for it. Microsoft docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#dns